# Fetch maximum and minimum time from ms access db using php

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

I am trying to work with an existing database created in Microsoft Access Database. This database has one table named `CHECKINOUT` which storing data of the finger print check time of every user following sequence-

```
USERID         CHECKTIME        CHECKTYPE            VERIFYCODE
=======================================================
3         10/03/2013 7:03:32 PM   I             1   
3         10/03/2013 11:45:49 AM  I             1
3         10/03/2013 8:40:20 AM   I             1
3         11/03/2013 7:13:33 PM   I             1
3         11/03/2013 11:24:36 PM  I             1
3         11/03/2013 9:04:42 AM  I              1
4         10/03/2013 7:02:46 PM   I             1
4         10/03/2013 6:43:10 PM   I             1
4         10/03/2013 10:46:41 AM  I             1
4         10/03/2013 8:47:04 AM   I             1
4         11/03/2013 7:23:33 PM   I             1
4         11/03/2013 11:20:36 PM  I             1
4         11/03/2013 8:28:42 AM  I              1
```

Now, let me pick the minimum and maximum time manually.

```
10 March UserID(3) Maximum Time: 10/03/2013 7:03:32 PM
10 March UserID(3) Minimum Time: 10/03/2013 8:40:20 AM
11 March UserID(3) Maximum Time: 11/03/2013 7:13:33 PM
11 March UserID(3) Minimum Time: 11/03/2013 9:04:42 AM


10 March UserID(4) Maximum Time: 10/03/2013 7:02:46 PM
10 March UserID(4) Minimum Time: 10/03/2013 8:47:04 AM
11 March UserID(4) Maximum Time: 11/03/2013 11:20:36 PM
11 March UserID(4) Minimum Time: 11/03/2013 8:28:42 AM
```

Now I would like to write a query to pick individual(e.g. Where UserID = 3) minimum and maximum time from `CHECKTIME` column from `CHECKINOUT` table using php. Report should look like below-

```
USERID      |   DAY        |    INTIME(MINIMUM TIME)     | OUTTIME(MAXIMUM TIME)
=================================================================================
   3        | 10/03/2013   |        8:40:20 AM           |     7:03:32 PM
   3        | 11/03/2013   |        9:04:42 AM           |     7:13:33 PM
```

How May I achieve above query using PHP from MS Access(.mdb) database? I think it is possible using sub-query. But, I can't find any query browser like HeidiSQL, MySQL Query Browser, MySQL Terminal or Navicat for MS Access where should I write and test my query.

Comment: Please check the last output table I have created in description. I would like to pick like that day wise..

Comment: yes... you are right... I am wrong at description... let me modify

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about access but the general query should be like this:

```
SELECT
  date(checktime) Day,
  time(min(checktime)) MinTime,
  time(max(checktime)) MaxTime
FROM t
WHERE userid = 3
GROUP BY Day
```

I created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c697e/1) with MySQL but turning this into MsAccess should be very simple. Disregard the weird date format... that is something SQLFiddle is changing but `Date()` and `Time()` should only return the appropriate part of the datetime instead of setting the year to 1970 and that stuff.

Comment: `Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'DATE(CHECKTIME) Day'., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in`

Comment: I have tried the same query from my knowledge of MySQL. I am appreciating your answer.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, the query runs in MySQL. You have to turn it into MsAccess (look for date time functions in MsAccess and replace the `date` and `time` functions with the ones MsAccess expects... it is just a syntactical issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like anviz db ;)
Maybe it will be helpful for someone..
MS Access request from att2003.mdb v_record request:

```
SELECT 
First(V_Record.Userid) AS [USER ID], 
First(V_Record.Name) AS Employer,
DateValue([CheckTime]) AS Date, Min(TimeValue([CheckTime])) AS CheckIN,
Max(TimeValue([CheckTime])) AS CheckOUT, 
Format(Max(TimeValue([CheckTime]))-Min(TimeValue([CheckTime])),"hh:nn") AS [Work Time],
First(V_Record.Sensorid) AS [Device ID], 
First(V_Record.ClientName) AS [Device name]
FROM V_Record
GROUP BY DateValue([V_Record.CheckTime]), V_Record.Userid
ORDER BY DateValue([V_Record.CheckTime]), First(V_Record.Name);
```